# Typography in React Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, typography

I've this textbox:

```
<Typography component="p" className={classes.text}>
        {this.props.post.text}
</Typography>
```

I'd like to be able to include paragraphs but all text entered into it gets printed on one line.

The documentation suggests that `paragraph` is defaulted to `false` so I must set it to `true.

I've tried the following:

```
<Typography component="p" className={classes.text} paragraph="true">
```

I also tried:

```
<Typography component="p" className={classes.text} paragraph={true}>
```

Neither work so all my text still gets printed to one line.

How do I get the paragraphs to show?

**Additional info:**
As I now understand, the paragraph={true} attribute in Typography just [adds a bottom-margin to the whole text](https://material-ui.com/api/typography/). I.E. my one block of text is a paragraph. If I want another paragraph I would have to add another `Typography`. Something like:

```
<Typography component="p" className={classes.text} paragraph={true}>
        {this.props.post.text}
</Typography>
<Typography component="p" className={classes.text} paragraph={true}>
        {this.props.post.text2}
</Typography>
```

This is not exactly what I want. Perhaps what I should be aiming for is to have the return characters in my input text recognised. Is this correct and if so, how is it done?

I tried this:

```
  <pre>
    <Typography component="p" className={classes.text}>
      {this.props.post.text}
    </Typography>
  </pre>
```

The  tag preservers the whitespace and line breaks inside the tags as is.

This is not suitable though. If I have long line the text does not wrap at the Card width. Instead anything beyond the width of the card becomes truncated. Clearly I want it all. I want my text to wrap in the card and also for it to support new lines and paragraphs. How is this done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For new paragraphs

```
<Typography>
  {this.props.text.split("\n").map((i, key) => {
    return <p key={key}>{i}</p>;
  })}
</Typography>
```

For just new lines

```
<Typography>
  {this.props.text.split("\n").map((i, key) => {
    return <div key={key}>{i}</div>;
  })}
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 18):

A better way is to use power of css:

```
white-space: pre-line
```

"New line" character will be respected if you use this css property.

Edit: Help from Ionut-Alexandru Baltariu

```
<Typography id="modal-description" sx={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-line'}}>
```

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: Adapted for inline styling:                    `<Typography id="modal-description" sx={{
                        whiteSpace: 'pre-line'
                    }}>`

Answer (score 5):

I've come up with this:

```
<Typography component="p" className={classes.text}>
  {this.props.post.text.split("\n").map((i, key) => {
    return <p key={key}>{i}</p>;
  })}
</Typography>
```

If there is a better way to do this I'd be keen to hear it.

Answer (score 5):

I tried your answer and it worked perfectly as needed. However, the console returns a minor error

> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): `<p>` cannot appear as a descendant
>   of `<p>`.

I improved on your answer slightly by replacing the `<p>` tags in your `.map()` with `<Typography>` and wrapping it all in a `<div>` instead, like so:

```
<div className={classes.text}>
  {this.props.post.text.split('\n').map((i, key) => {
    return <Typography key={key} paragraph variant="body1">{i}</Typography>;
  })}
</div>
```

(you can replace `body1` with whichever variant you want!)

This seems to get rid of the warning for me and I hope works as you intended.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
<Typography component="pre">
   {this.props.post.text}
</Typography>
```

And in CSS:

```
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;       /* Since CSS 2.1 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
  word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This really is a strange behavior. From what I can tell, you are doing everything correctly. p is by itself displayed as block element so it should be by default displayed the way you want it to be. But, it could be that you are overriding that in your `.text` css class. Try to see if there is you problem. If not, you can always use variant property `variant="headline"` in order to put them on new lines.

Comment: Thanks @Lazar Nikolic. I've now spent some time looking at this and can't figure it out. I'm not overriding it in my `.text` css and I tried various variant settings but they make no difference.

Answer (score 1):

If I get this right, you could simply leverage the power of HTML and add `<br />`-elements, to insert line-breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Material UI V5 you can now access many CSS utilities as props. For whitespace, you can now do:

```
<Typography whiteSpace="pre-line">{this.props.post.text}</Typography>
```